# AWS won't let me terminate an environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to terminate an Elastic Beanstalk environment but it fails due to:

```
Deleting security group named: awseb-e-gpxusz64rm-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1QZI37JXP423J failed Reason: resource sg-d25608b7 has a dependent object
```

Is there a way to force the environment to terminate?

Comment: Why are you trying to delete a security group in order to tear down an environment?

Comment: The security group stuff is a mystery to me. All I am trying to do is terminate an environment (or restore it back to its original state) but I get the following in the log: "ERROR Stack deletion failed: The following resource(s) failed to delete: [AWSEBSecurityGroup].". It seems to be stuck I can neither restore not terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Security Group will not be deleted as long as it's in use, most typically that means active instances in the group.  Elastic Beanstalk will remove it's own instances, and usually this works smoothly.  Sometimes you have to manually help it a bit.

It is also possible that there are instances or other resources not managed by Elastic Beanstalk that have been launched into the Security Group. Take a look in the EC2 Instances section of the AWS Management Console to see what is attached to that security group.  The quick way is to paste the Security Group name, `awseb-e-gpxusz64rm-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1QZI37JXP423J` into the filter search and let AWS give you the list.

An RDS database instance might also be the problem.

One thing that helps me manage Elastic Beanstalk stuff is to add a column to the console UI for the EB environment name.  Click the "Show/Hide Columns" button (gear icon) in the top right, and look for tag keys like `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` that can help you zero in on the right EB artifacts.  This works for both instances and security groups.

Comment: Using awseb-e-gpxusz64rm-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1QZI37JXP423J as a filter in the EC2 Instances pane and nothing comes up (I only have two instances in another EB application). Any idea of how I can check if it is an RDS database instance causing the issue and which one?

Comment: If I show the environment name column there is no name shown for the AWSEBSecurityGroup-1QZI37JXP423J.

Comment: The Instances list in the RDS console will show security groups if you enable the optional column.

Comment: I have added that column and no security groups are shown. In the security groups section of the RDS it says "Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported."

Comment: Strange, mine lists VPC security groups.  It is possible to go through your RDS instances one-by-one and check the security group.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. I have identified an RDS database that has that security group. Can I remove the security group from the database?

Comment: Yes, through Instance Actions -> modify.  But I think you need to have a new security group to add in order to drop the existing one.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this James. Can you point me at where to create a security group to add? That should be all I need then :)

Comment: All good! I found the security group creation stuff. Many thanks for your help it is greatly appreciated.